# Filter doesn't work: Error Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null

Tags: angular

I have a little filter search app, I pull out the data from MySQL database through spring API. everything worked well, but since I implemented `filterExpenses()` method in `list-expense.component.ts`, I get an ERROR

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null"

it is pointing the error lies in the line :

```js
return e.expense.toLowerCase().includes(this.filters.keyword.toLowerCase());
```

I've got no success as to how to get rid of this error.

Grateful if anyone can help me.

#### expense.ts (service)

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Expense } from '../models/expense';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ExpenseService {
  private getUrl: string = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/expenses';
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getExpenses(): Observable<Expense[]> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<Expense[]>(this.getUrl)
      .pipe(map((response) => response));
  }

  getExpense(id: number): Observable<Expense> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<Expense>(`${this.getUrl}/${id}`)
      .pipe(map((response) => response));
  }
}
```

#### list-expense.component.ts

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Expense } from 'src/app/models/expense';
import { ExpenseService } from 'src/app/services/expense.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-expense',
  templateUrl: './list-expense.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-expense.component.css'],
})
export class ListExpenseComponent implements OnInit {
  filters = {
    keyword: '',
  };
  expenses: Expense[];
  constructor(private expenseService: ExpenseService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.listExpenses();
  }

  listExpenses() {
    this.expenseService
      .getExpenses()
      .subscribe((data) => (this.expenses = this.filterExpenses(data)));
  }

  filterExpenses(expenses: Expense[]) {
    return expenses.filter((e) => {
      // Error on this line
      return e.expense
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(this.filters.keyword.toLowerCase());
    });
  }
}
```

#### list-expense.component.html

```html
<a routerLink="/addexpense">Add Expense</a>

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filters.keyword" name="keyword" (input)="listExpenses()">

<div *ngFor="let expense of expenses">
  <h3>{{expense.expense}}</h3>
  <h3>{{expense.amount | currency: 'CHF'}}</h3>

  <a routerLink="/editexpense/{{expense.id}}">Edit</a>
  <button (click)="deleteExpense(expense.id)">Delete</button>
</div>
<a routerLink="/addexpense">Add Expense</a>

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filters.keyword" name="keyword" (input)="listExpenses()">

<div *ngFor="let expense of expenses">
  <h3>{{expense.expense}}</h3>
  <h3>{{expense.amount | currency: 'CHF'}}</h3>

  <a routerLink="/editexpense/{{expense.id}}">Edit</a>
  <button (click)="deleteExpense(expense.id)">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the structure of your `Expense` model? @TheKash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely happening because there's an object in the array with an `expense` of `null`.

So consider using [Typescript Optional Chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) so that when `e.expense` is `null` it doesn't try to execute the `toLowerCase()` method.

So that line should look like this

```js
return e.expense?.toLowerCase().includes(this.filters.keyword.toLowerCase());
```

You can also use a plain if statement like this

```js
filterExpenses(expenses: Expense[]) {
  return expenses.filter((e) => {
    if (!e.expense) {
      return;
    }
    return e.expense
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(this.filters.keyword.toLowerCase());
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are receiving a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null" error, this means that the value that you are performing the "toLowerCase" function is not a string. e.expense is most likely not a string, a number, or null. Try printing the value of e.expense and seeing what the problem is.